# How can I match part of url with c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a dynamic list like following lines

https://www.example.com/*/post/

https://www.example2.com/videos/*

https://www.example3.com/photo/

How can I match with C# following urls (return true)

https://www.example.com/user123/post/

http://www.example.com/user123/post/abc

https://www.example2.com/videos/1234

https://www.example2.com/videos/1234/5678

http://www.example2.com/videos/1234/5678

http://example2.com/videos/1234/video.asp?id=1

maybe I can use UriTemplate but urls have a lot of part. they don't have static format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method, which uses regular expressions:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var urls = new string[] { "https://www.example.com/*/post/", "https://www.example2.com/videos/*" };
  // here regex patterns are created: special characters are escaped and 
  // star, which means here "anything" is replaced by .+ which means "one or more of any charaters"
  var regexes = urls.Select(url => new Regex(url.Replace("/", @"\/").Replace(".", @"\.").Replace("*", ".+")));

  var toCheck = new string[]
  {
  "https://www.example.com/user123/post/",
  "http://www.example.com/user123/post/abc",
  "https://www.example2.com/videos/1234",
  "https://www.example2.com/videos/1234/5678",
  "http://www.example2.com/videos/1234/5678",
  "http://example2.com/videos/1234/video.asp?id=1"
  };

  var valid = toCheck.Where(url => regexes.Where(r => r.Match(url).Success).Any()).ToArray();
}
```